# Host Traditional ASP.NET Website to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have a ASP.NET Web Application, based on layering architecture (DAL, Model & View), .NET Framework 4.0, C# as Server Side language, SQL Server 2008, SAP Crystal Reports. Currently it is hosted on a local server. Now client want to host it at some online server. I was thinking to host it on Azure, as it is getting very hot these days.

Is it possible that I can host my web application at Azure, without making any change in it? As It is very matured and bug free. I don't want to make any change in it and don't want to test everything again.

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/27/how-to-plan-your-migration-to-azure-websites/

Answer (score 0):

You can start by taking the entire website and hosting it on Azure Websites.
You can play around with Azure Websites here : [https://trywebsites.azurewebsites.net](http://portal.azure.com)
Try creating an Azure Website by login in through the [Azure Management Portal](http://portal.azure.com)